# Web Scraping Loop for Dynamic Pages

Tags: python, selenium, loops, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape reviews from this site. It starts off with only showing 3 reviews, and every time you press "show more reviews" it reveals 3 more. I was able to make the code click on the "show more reviews" button but when I tried to print out the reviews after clicking the button, I only got the first 3 reviews twice. How do I loop it so that it keeps clicking and collecting new reviews until the very end?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Sara Jitkresorn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://boxes.mysubscriptionaddiction.com/box/boxycharm?ratings=true#review-update-create")
df = pd.DataFrame()

review = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("comment-body")
for post in review:
    print(post.text)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="user-reviews"]/div[2]/div[1]/a').click()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
review2 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("comment-body")
for post in review2:
    print(post.text)

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'Reviews':review2})
    df = df.append(temp_df, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

df.to_csv('subsaddictTest01.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
print ('excel done')
```

This is the result I got from the code

> I think Boxycharm overall is the best beauty subscription. However, I think it's ridiculous that if you want to upgrade you have to pay the 25 for the first box and then add additional money to get the premium. Even though it's only one time, that's insane. So about 80 bucks just to switch to Premi...read more
>
> I love getting the monthly boxes, just wish they would have followed my preferences for colors!
>
> I used to really get excited for my boxes. But not so much anymore. This months Fenty box choices lack!
>
> I am not a clown
>
> I think Boxycharm overall is the best beauty subscription. However, I think it's ridiculous that if you want to upgrade you have to pay the 25 for the first box and then add additional money to get the premium. Even though it's only one time, that's insane. So about 80 bucks just to switch to Premi...read more
>
> I love getting the monthly boxes, just wish they would have followed my preferences for colors!
>
> I used to really get excited for my boxes. But not so much anymore. This months Fenty box choices lack!
>
> I am not a clown

The data collected within the excel sheet is also weird. Here is a sample from one of the rows in the excel generated by this code.

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="2ff48075e18712a7ffb62a1dc1a88ad1", element="487f7764-e4e4-40f6-81ec-bbf3a5bacce3")>
```

Comment: The reson why your data in excel file is returning like ```<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="2ff48075e18712a7ffb62a1dc1a88ad1", element="487f7764-e4e4-40f6-81ec-bbf3a5bacce3")>``` is that you didn't put **.text**  after ```review2``` in this line ```temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'Reviews':review2})```. Do it like this ```review2.text```.

Comment: i did as you told, but got an error 'list' object has no attribute 'text'. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Just Put ```brackets``` on ```review2``` first like this ```({"Reviews" : [review2.text]})``` Ping me out if you get any errors after doing this also.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Hey Sara, just put ```post.text``` instead of ```reviews2.text``` because reviews2 is a list. And you are iterating it using a for loop named post to break it.

Answer (score 0):

for excel go through that list items and then use ***.text***
and for getting comments first make and account and see if you can access this [link](https://boxes.mysubscriptionaddiction.com/get_user_reviews?box_id=105&page=2)

Comment: I logged in with Facebook and clicked the link. But got this "The change you wanted was rejected.
Maybe you tried to change something you didn't have access to."